# Optimizing the popBack method for your own list implementation

Tags: c++

I am writing my own implementation of a single linked list. I wrote a `popBack()` method, but it seems to me that it is too overloaded with conditional operators, which should affect performance (and in general, it looks so-so). Is it possible to optimize it somehow so that it does not look so terrible?

```
void popBack() {
  if (head == nullptr) {
    return;
  }
  if (head->next == nullptr) {
    delete head;
    head = nullptr;
  }
  else {
    Node* prev = nullptr;
    Node* curr = head;
    while(curr->next != nullptr) {
      prev = curr;
      curr = curr->next;
    }
    if(prev != nullptr) {
      delete curr;
      prev->next = nullptr;
    }
  }
  size--;
}
```

Comment: Don't just guess/assume that pieces of code will visibly affect performance. Benchmark and profile, and only then should you decide to worry about optimizing code performance, and only in the places that the profilers indicate are significant. In your case your few early returns / branches will have little to no performance impact, especially considering all the cache misses incurred by using a linked list in the first place.

Comment: Even [std::forward_list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list), which is basically a singly-linked list, doesn't have a `back()` or `pop_back()` function.  Note that there are `front` and `pop_front` functions that exist.

Answer (score 2):

The 2nd `if` block is not necessary. Also, the `else` block can be simplified if you use a `Node**` pointer to point at the `Node*` variable which needs to be `null`'ed when the `Node` object it is pointing at is `delete`'d, eg:

```
void popBack() {
  if (!head) return;
  Node *curr = head, **prev = &head;
  while (curr->next) {
    prev = &(curr->next);
    curr = *prev;
  }
  *prev = nullptr;
  delete curr;
  --size;
}
```

Of course, if you really want to optimize the popping, you should implement a double-linked list instead, and add a `tail` member to your list class to point at the last `Node` in the list, then you won't need a `while` loop to hunt for the trailing `Node`s in the list, eg:

```
void popBack() {
  if (!tail) return;
  Node *curr = tail;
  tail = tail->previous;
  Node **n = (tail) ? &(tail->next) : &head;
  *n = nullptr;
  delete curr;
  --size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One technique that can clean the code up a lot is to ensure the list always includes one node that you basically treat as empty. You never use the value it contains, but it eliminates many of the corner cases, so most of the code never had to deal with them.

Using this, `pop_back` can end up something like this:

```cpp
void pop_back() {
    if (head->next == nullptr)
        return; // empty list--nothing to do.

    // traverse to just before the sentinel node:
    node* loc;
    for (loc = head; loc->next->next != nullptr; loc = loc->next)
        ;

    // at this point, `loc` points to the last "real" node in the list
    // delete the old sentinel node
    // then turn this into the sentinel node by setting its next pointer
    // to a null pointer:
    delete loc->next;
    loc->next = nullptr;
}
```

Of course, to make this work, we have to assure the list always contains the sentinel node:

```cpp
    LinkedList() {
        // node with its next pointer set to a null pointer:
        head = new node(nullptr);
    }
```

...and (of course) `push_back` has to be aware of the sentinel as well:

```cpp
void push_back(T t) {
    if (head->next == nullptr) {
        head = new node(t, head);
        return;
    }

    node* loc;
    for (loc = head; loc->next->next != nullptr; loc = loc->next)
        ;

    loc->next = new node(t, loc->next);
}
```

We can also carry this a step further by saving the location of the sentinel node. Although we still need to traverse the list to do a `pop_back`, we can avoid it when we want to do a `push_back` (we put the new value into the current sentinel node, then allocate a new sentinel node, and update our tail pointer to its location.

This general approach is, however, restricted to types that we don't mind creating a default-constructed item that we don't (currently) use. In my experience that's true a lot more often than not, but there are exceptions for which this design isn't suitable.